# Unicode for single backticks

Tags: ubuntu, backticks

How can I insert single backticks on ubuntu?

this:

> `

For simple it's like: '

Which unicode exist for simple backticks?

Comment: maybe a better question for [ask ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Er where do you want to insert them?

Comment: Anywhere for example browser, or .doc file

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl + shif + u` + `0060` + `enter`

If you've used windows, you have combinations with `alt + number`.

In Linux we can use symbols by using `ctrl + shift + u` + *their unicode number* + `enter`, so the code enters.

When you press `ctrl + shift + u` you should se an u̲ (an underlined u), it means it's waiting for the unicode number to be entered, after the u̲ appears, you don't have to hold `ctrl + shift + u` anymore. Just enter the unicode, and press enter.